# Subclassing UITextView to allow for multiple colors

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, colors, uitextview

I want to make a compiler-esque `UITextView` subclass to allow for different sections of the text to be different colors, because I know that normally a `UITextView` only allows for 1 color for the whole thing. Does anyone know how to do that? And I dont want to use UIWebView because I want it to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have fully customized text, then the simplest (best?) thing to so is simply to use a `UIWebView` instead.

Comment: Yes I can do that but I want it to be editable and the html will not be as easy to edit on the iphone itself

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CATextLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) or, if you need more than simple rendering, [CoreText](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533).